# Why doesn't my HTTPS connection use TLS?

Tags: ssl, https, jboss7.x, wireshark

*I hope you'll excuse my bad / poor english.*

I'm pretty sure it's a quite naïve question, but I need to be fixed about it.

I'm running an application on a JBOSS AS 7 server, and I enabled HTTPS connection by adding this lines in my standalone.xml file :

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
    <ssl name="ssl" password="password" protocol="TLSv1"/>
</connector>
```

Now, if I try to acces my application through a web browser using this url :

```
https://localhost:8443/myapp/
```

After I accept my homemade certificate, the browser tell me that the connection is made using TLS protocol, and encrypted by an AES 128. Everything looks fine.

But when I use Wireshark on the server, and I try to access my application with a computer located in my local network, there is no trace of TLS, but only TCP connections (which seem to be encrypted).

On the other hand, if I try to access to an HTTPS web server, Wireshark is telling me that the protocol in use is TLS. I'm quite confuse now.

So here are my questions : Is my connection even so working on TLS ? If not, what could be the problem (Could it be the port 8443 which is not the HTTPS' standard port ?) ?

Let me know if I'm not really clear, or if I didn't give enough informations.

Best regards,
PDauph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that your connection is using TLS.  Wireshark does not automatically recognize all protocols.  It uses heuristics, including the port number, to try to determine the layered protocols on a connection.  If you are using a non-standard port (like 8443) then Wireshark probably isn't interpreting the connection as TLS even though it actually is.

You can manually tell Wireshark to decode a connection as a specific protocol when it doesn't choose the correct one by itself.  Right-click on one of the packets and choose "Decode As..." from the context menu.  Then choose SSL as the Transport protocol.  Wireshark should now try to parse the connection as a SSL/TLS stream.

Here is the [documentation on Wireshark decoding](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustProtocolDissectionSection.html).

Comment: Thanks ! I was suspecting the 8443 port, but not because of Wireshark, thanks for pointing this out. Doing the "Decode As..." manipulation let me see the "key exchange", "encrypted handshake", and other phases the TLS protocol need.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed caused because, by default, Wireshark does not consider 8443 to establish a HTTPS/SSL connection.

In addition to dealing with decoders, this can be configured rather easily in the preferences:

1. Open up the Preferences (menu: Edit -> Preferences, key: Ctrl+Shift+P)
2. Choose the Protocols -> HTTP preference page
3. Then for SSL/TLS Ports use "443,**8443**" (or as appropriate)

Then the next time data is captured it will have appropriate HTTPS/SSL decoder applied.

Comment: Seems useful to me. Not sure why this was downvoted.